# Using OpenJDK (Microsoft Java) in an Dev Ops Pipeline

Tags: java, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using an PowerShell command to download the latest version of OpenJDK (bits download)

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "https://aka.ms/download-jdk/microsoft-jdk-17-windows-x64.zip"
```

And then I am unzipping it like this :

```
Expand-Archive -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(zipFile) -DestinationPath $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Java
```

And then I am setting the Java environmental variables like this :

```
$JavaHome = '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)' + "\" + "Java" + "\" + "jdk-17.0.2+8"

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", $JavaHome)

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine) + ";$($env:JAVA_HOME)\bin")
```

Then lastly I am using the version check in Java to see what version i am using and I get this :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

This is not the one I downloaded, I downloaded

```
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18 LTS
```

So I am sure within my pipeline it is using the Java that was on the machine already. So how can I make sure it is using the one I have downloaded and set the environmental variables up for. If I check on my pipeline I cannot see a JAVA PATH at all - so it must be using mine.

The only reason I am using the downloaded one is so I can use the latest (LTS) when it comes available.

Comment: Can you not use the task? [Java Tool Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer?view=azure-devops)

Comment: No! Cos the management want the latest LTS version.. I keep saying that would be the easiest option!

Comment: One thing you could do is have a pre-task that downloads your latest version and moves it temporarily to a storage account (using azcopy). If you save the file name as a variable, you could still use the Java Tool Installer task. It just seems convenient that you don't have to worry about setting the environment variables.

Comment: that an idea :)